# XGBoost Regressor cannot fit the model using string data

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, xgboost

I'm trying to use XGBoost to predict a one target (one attribute) dataframe. Below my code. I run it on Colab

```
!sudo pip install xgboost
!sudo pip install --upgrade xgboost
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = [['sp37n1sy1bmjc6yp3m7wqefpz' ], ['sp36vfqtjv87pvw68zdmhnvxb'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36vues2ed9r6s196dmv4p00'], ['sp36vvgq6rq9sq1gv0nt19h20'], ['sp36ypgx7jmmsuujz2ww81n20'], ['sp37n1w451m6wtp6h4eq0wjb0'], ['sp36y99s6w9jm3614ugt52bpz'], ['sp37n1mywgv57qsg5r7hp7bpz'], ['sp36y9fbfz4t9c5znp27z3pbp']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
X = data[:-1]
y = data[1:]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
regressor = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators=100,
    reg_lambda=1,
    gamma=0,
    max_depth=3
)
regressor.fit(str(X_train), str(y_train))
```

However, the following error is returned:

```
XGBoostError: [17:00:27] /workspace/dmlc-core/src/io/local_filesys.cc:86: LocalFileSystem.GetPathInfo: [['sp36ypgx7jmmsuujz2ww81n20'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp37n1w451m6wtp6h4eq0wjb0'], ['sp36vvgq6rq9sq1gv0nt19h20'], ['sp36vfqtjv87pvw68zdmhnvxb'], ['sp37n1sy1bmjc6yp3m7wqefpz'], ['sp37n1mywgv57qsg5r7hp7bpz'], ['sp36vues2ed9r6s196dmv4p00'], ['sp36y99s6w9jm3614ugt52bpz']] error: File name too long
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(dmlc::io::LocalFileSystem::GetPathInfo(dmlc::io::URI const&)+0x567) [0x7f6f13f157c7]
  [bt] (1) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(dmlc::io::InputSplitBase::InitInputFileInfo(std::string const&, bool)+0x14e) [0x7f6f13f044de]
  [bt] (2) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(dmlc::io::InputSplitBase::Init(dmlc::io::FileSystem*, char const*, unsigned long, bool)+0x43) [0x7f6f13f04be3]
  [bt] (3) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(dmlc::InputSplit::Create(char const*, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*, bool, int, unsigned long, bool)+0xb7a) [0x7f6f13eed18a]
  [bt] (4) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(dmlc::InputSplit::Create(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*)+0x1e) [0x7f6f13eed81e]
  [bt] (5) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(dmlc::Parser<unsigned int, float>* dmlc::data::CreateLibSVMParser<unsigned int, float>(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x1a) [0x7f6f13ecb09a]
  [bt] (6) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(dmlc::Parser<unsigned int, float>* dmlc::data::CreateParser_<unsigned int, float>(char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, char const*)+0x15b) [0x7f6f13ebc23b]
  [bt] (7) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(xgboost::DMatrix::Load(std::string const&, bool, bool, std::string const&, unsigned long)+0x2df) [0x7f6f13c91a0f]
  [bt] (8) /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so(XGDMatrixCreateFromFile+0xc2) [0x7f6f13c5f5b2]
```

if I change the last line to

```
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: can not initialize DMatrix from list
```

What I'm doing wrong? any clue?

Comment: XGBoost only handles numeric values. So convert strings to numeric labels using encoders.

Comment: Is this regression or classification? Please update the question

Comment: How can I convert string to numeric using encoders? since the samples contains letters it is not possible to convert it directly integer. I'll update the question to regressor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XGBoost cannot handle categorical variables, so they need to be encoded before passing to XGBoost model. There are many ways you can encode your varaibles according to the nature of the categorical variable. Since I believe that your string have some order so Label Encoding is suited for your categorical variables:

Full code:

```py
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
data = [['sp37n1sy1bmjc6yp3m7wqefpz' ], ['sp36vfqtjv87pvw68zdmhnvxb'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36y965ksqnmq0b0b58y1p00'], ['sp36vues2ed9r6s196dmv4p00'], ['sp36vvgq6rq9sq1gv0nt19h20'], ['sp36ypgx7jmmsuujz2ww81n20'], ['sp37n1w451m6wtp6h4eq0wjb0'], ['sp36y99s6w9jm3614ugt52bpz'], ['sp37n1mywgv57qsg5r7hp7bpz'], ['sp36y9fbfz4t9c5znp27z3pbp']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
X = df[:-1]
y = df[1:]

le = LabelEncoder()

X = le.fit_transform(X)
y = le.fit_transform(y)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1,1) #convert to 2D

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

regressor = xgb.XGBRegressor(
    n_estimators=100,
    reg_lambda=1,
    gamma=0,
    max_depth=3
)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
y_predictions = [int(round(y,0)) for y in y_pred]
print("Encoded Predictions",y_predictions) #encoded predictions
print("String predictions",le.inverse_transform(y_predictions)) #original string predictions
print()
print("Encoded Actual value",y_test) #encoded
print("String Actual value",le.inverse_transform(y_test)) #original test values
```

Comment: It doesn't return an error now. However, the value is reduced to three digits values, is it possible to recover the original string value?

Comment: Yes it is possible to recover the original string. Use `le.inverse_transform()` method. Check the updated answer